# Exotic pet questions

Tags: feature-request

I would like to make a suggestion that when asking a question regarding to exotic pets,  mainly reptiles and amphibians,  there should be a specific template.

Ex.
Tank size and make (glass or mesh)

Substrate

Temperatures of hot and cold side

Temperature of water (for aquatic species)

Humidity %

UV lighting - coil, tube or MVB (last time it was changed)

Feeding schedule,  what they are feeding, any vit/min additives with frequency
Pictures of setup are ideal

99% of reptile problems have to do with their setup,  would be nice to have this implemented so we see the whole picture at once.

Comment: The general system doesn't really lend itself to that, you would almost need to put a wizard flow in place to make it work.

Comment: You might ask and answer yourself a general question the address all of those points, and include a link to it in comments when reaching out to people with new questions. P.S. Thanks for all the work you have done to support the community and help the pets.

Comment: @johncavan thanks for the input, I may save it on a word file and present it when needed.

Comment: @JamesJenkins You're welcome :P my SO introduced me to it, he's pretty active on the programmers section.

Answer (score 4):

A template would be a great addition to the site, and could be linked from comments, relevant tag wikis, and perhaps pages in the help center.

On another of my sites we've used templates for certain kinds of posts (for special projects, not main-site questions), and what worked best for us was to have a post on meta that has the instructions and markdown ready for people to cut and paste.  [Here is an example](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3941/472).

Comment: what would we do to have to implement such a thing?

Comment: @YvetteColomb in my opinion: create a template with cut/paste-ready markdown, post it on meta, link to it from the relevant tag wiki(s), and start directing people to it in comments and encouraging its use.  See how it goes and refine.